# How can the spelling of a tag be changed?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-request

I recently wrote my first tag wiki for the [namedranges](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/namedranges) tag because I noticed several questions had been applied the tag, and there was no information about the tag.

I would really like to change the tag to [named-ranges](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/named-ranges) (hyphenated) to follow the convention used here for multi-word tags. Is there a way to do this automatically, or do I have to go the tag synonym route?

Also, if the spelling is changed, will the corrected tag have to be applied to old questions manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a tag merge for you. That renames all existing tags, created a synonym, and copies over the tag wiki.

Comment: Thanks, @nhinkle!